# Cleaning up pandas column of datetime strings

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have some data in the form of datestrings that I would like to standardize into a zero-padded %H:%M:%S string. In its original form, the data deviates from the standard format in the following ways:

- The time is not zero padded (e.g. '2:05:00')
- There can be trailing whitespaces (e.g., ' 2:05:00')
- There can be times over 24H displayed (e.g., '25:00:00')

Currently, this is what I have:

```
df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'].map(lambda x: x.strip()), format='%H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

But I get an error on the times that are over 24H. Is there a good way to transform this dataframe column into the proper format?

Comment: What do you do with it if it's over 24 hours? NaN?

Comment: To clarify, I'm doing this with GTFS data, which specifies times over 24H if a trip runs overnight.

Comment: That didn't answer my question, but okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'arrival_time':['2:05:00','2:05:00','25:00:00'],})

df['arrival_time'] = df['arrival_time'].str.strip().str.zfill(8)
print (df)
  arrival_time
0     02:05:00
1     02:05:00
2     25:00:00
```

Or:

```
df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_time'].str.strip(), errors='coerce')
                       .dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
  arrival_time
0     02:05:00
1     02:05:00
2          NaT
```

Or:

```
df['arrival_time'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['arrival_time'].str.strip())
                        .astype(str)
                        .str.extract('\s.*\s(.*)\.', expand=False))
print (df)
  arrival_time
0     02:05:00
1     02:05:00
2     01:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you! The top answer is what ended up working for me.